# Trouble with initial distribution of C# .NET application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I've written an application in C# .NET with the WinForms UI toolkit.  I'm attempting to provide Windows executables, but so far they simply don't work for anyone but me.

I'm creating the release packages by building the EXE and DLLs in Visual Studio 2017, copying them into one place, and putting that into a .zip archive.  I'm not doing the fancy one-click publishing stuff.

The project is available on github (https://github.com/fadden/6502bench).  The first person to try it got "<program> has stopped working" on Win7 ([see issue](https://github.com/fadden/6502bench/issues/1)).  The second person was using Win10 Pro, and extracted some details from the event log that show it crashing in a system DLL ([see issue](https://github.com/fadden/6502bench/issues/2)).  Both of them have the latest .NET framework installed.

I haven't worked with C# .NET outside Unity, so I'm a bit out of my depth.  It's entirely possible I've skipped an "obvious" step, or am doing things wrong.

**Update:** answering some of the comments:

- it's pure C#, no native or unsafe code
- both people reporting problems confirmed that that latest .NET framework is installed (4.7.2)
- the program doesn't seem to be starting at all, so I'm not sure what the app could be doing wrong as far as local paths go
- the specific errors, including screen shots and log messages, are included in the issues linked above
- the full source code, with the VS solution and projects, is up on github

The sense I'm getting from the comments is that what I'm doing isn't fundamentally wrong, so there's some devil in the details.

Comment: What version of the .NET runtime are you compiling against?  Make sure it is installed on the target OS

Comment: There are so many possible issues. Maybe you are using local paths. Maybe you are hiding exceptions. This is too broad to answer. You have to provide specific errors people are getting and related code.

Comment: If you want a more robust solution, try WiX: http://wixtoolset.org/

Comment: is it pure c#? are you doing any native stuff?

Comment: Now you know that using the actual installer isn't pointless, and it's actually worth using because it's able to resolve these types of problems.  That's its job.

Comment: I can easily reproduce the issue, but it is a stack overflow caused by your code https://github.com/fadden/6502bench/issues/3 So in fact, it has nothing to do with "distributing", "packaging" or "dependencies" yet. The first step is to achieve correctness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downloaded the source, and debugged.

I received a `StackOverFlowException` on the following 2 lines of code.

#### ProjectView.cs

`line 3545` : `symbolListView.Columns[2].Width = lastWidth;`

`line 3719` : `referencesListView.Columns[2].Width = lastWidth;`

What is going on is you are handling the `ColumnWidthChanged` event on `ListView` components, and modifying the column width.  This modification fires the event again, which is causing an infinite loop, and a subsequent `StackOverflowException`.

---

But why? I'll take a swing at an answer. You may have hard coded some values that line up with the DPI and resolution of your monitor.  When the `ListView` instantiates on your machine, it doesn't have to 'redraw' the column with and does not fire the event, but for anyone else that doesn't have the same resolution and DPI, the event fires and causes the loop. I could be wrong, but sounds plausible to me.

Comment: Seems like this should be blowing up consistently on my system, unless somehow I have magic libraries that don't set the column width if the new value is the same as the old value. I can drag the windows and columns around and nothing fails. (The goal was to make the width of the last listview column such that it takes up the remaining space in the window.) Hopefully my supra-system isn't hiding any other problems.