# System-specific ListView column width change behavior

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Background: earlier today I posted an open-source app, written in C# .NET with WinForms, [on github](https://github.com/fadden/6502bench).  The first couple of people who downloaded it found that it crashed immediately on startup.  Assuming I'd screwed up the distribution somehow, I [posted a question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52561587/294248) here.  Some helpful people downloaded the project and quickly determined that the problem was caused by a stack overflow.

So that's resolved, but the question remains: why doesn't this code blow up when I run it?

The specific problem was caused by code that attempted to resize the rightmost column of a details-mode ListView whenever the size of the window or of another column changed.  A `ColumnWidthChanged` event handler was setting the width of a column, resulting in infinite recursion.

On my system, it works just fine ([here's video](https://youtu.be/9zrCD0BP_w8)).  One possible explanation would be that I have a special version of WinForms (or the underlying control) that doesn't post an event change notification if the column width hasn't changed.

What I really want is to have a high degree of confidence that code that works on my system will work elsewhere.  The people who answered my question seemed to have no difficulty reproducing the crash on their development systems.  Did I manage to install some sort of "bulletproof edition"?

The app and library projects target either .NET Framework 4.6.1 or .NET Standard 2.0.  Changing the app to target 4.7.1 had no effect.  I'm using Visual Studio Community 2017, updated through 15.8.3, on a Windows 10 Pro system.  This is my first attempt at a desktop C# .NET app, so I may be doing something silly.

**Update:** inspired by a comment from @jwdonahue I conducted an experiment: in the event handler, grab a `StackTrace` and check the `FrameCount`, recording the largest value seen.  With one of the column updates enabled, I consistently see a max frame count of 414, with multiple instances of the `ColumnWidthChanged` event handler present.  If I comment out the column update, the max count drops to 174, and I only see one instance of the event.

The stack trace from a failed run forwarded by @LexLi has 5087 entries, so it's not a simple matter of my stack limit being higher.

Comment: It's probably a timing thing. Either your machine is super-fast or super-slow relative to the others. I haven't looked at your code yet, but given the event handler, I wonder if you guard against reentrancy?

Comment: @jwdonahue: interesting -- a race condition could explain it, depending on how the event mechanism works. The code is not expecting to be reentered, and is broken as written. (Kind of embarrassing really, but I'll use "I'm new to WinForms" as an excuse.)

Comment: Ya, "works for me" is not a valid test suite. [This page on C# locks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/lock-statement) might be useful.

Comment: Also, some mice hardware and user's mouse settings can lead to interesting timing/repeating on some systems. Arthritis is another factor. My Mom always finds ways to open multiple windows or cause multiple operations of one kind or another, simply because her hands are bent.

Comment: I don't think adding locking will help here -- everything I control happens on one thread (and I have a very long stack trace to prove it). The race would have to be between different threads inside the UI implementation, and would rely on reaching a point where the column width is changed but no event is queued as a result.

Comment: I am looking deeper now, but so far, it looks like your event handler is being entered before it has finished what it does. You get a cascade of events triggered by your own code's behavior.

Answer (score 0):

It might be that on your system it will eventually set the column width to the existing value. If the new value is the same as the current value then it might not trigger the changed event.

Possible reasons are:

- The startup window size might be different because of different DPI.
- The data might be different causing different widths on different systems.
- On the failing systems the width might not converge but alternate between two values.
- Theoretically it could depend on the version of the .net framework or OS.

Either way, from a practical standpoint it is best to design your software such that there are no circular calculations.